# Getting No valid responses from any peers. error when trying to "network start"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following the tutorial on: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/applications/web
To implement a frontend to my chain code. But when I try to put in the command:

`composer network start --networkName perishable-network --networkVersion 0.2.7-deploy.0 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1`

It gives me the error:

> ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is
>   not a valid endorsement system chaincode) Command failed

When I did `composer install` on my bna however I got this information which I am using in the `network start` command.

> ✔ Installing business network. This may take a minute... Successfully
>   installed business network perishable-network, version 0.2.7-deploy.0
>
> Command succeeded

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use Composer 0.20 with Hyperledger Fabric 1.1. Unfortunately they are not compatible. You should either downgrade to Composer 0.19 or upgrade your fabric for 1.2